# Are vectors $v(x) , u(x)$ and $w(x)$ linear dependent in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ if $u(x)=|x-2| , v(x)=|x-3| , w(x)=|x-5|?$

Tags: vectors

Are vectors $v(x) , u(x)$ and $w(x)$ linear dependent in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ if
$$
u(x)=|x-2|\\ v(x)=|x-3|\\w(x)=|x-5| ?$$

Comment: No. If you are looking for ideas or arguments, try giving some of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ such that $au+bv+vw=0$. This means:

(*) $a|x-2|+b|x-3|+c|x-5|=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Consider (*) for $x=2$, $x=3$ and $x=5$. These considerations give you a system of $3$ equations for $a,b,c$. Solve this system and look what happens !

Answer (score 1):

This vectors indeed are linearly independent.

Assume that they are not linearly independent.

Then exist  $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a_1,a_2,a_3 \neq 0$ and 
$a|x-2|+b|x-3|+c|x-5|=0$.

Then we have a contradiction because $0$ as a constant function is differentiable in all $\mathbb{R}$ but the left side of the equality is not defferentiable at the points $2,3,5$

Comment: A very fine argument !

Comment: @Fred thanks..your argument is also fine and quicker than mine

Comment: no, your argument is quicker.

Comment: either way your argument may be mor undestandable for more users especially those who may be not familiar with differentiability